# How can I query a Salesforce object to return only specific fields (columns)?

Tags: powerquery

I created a connection with Salesforce. Selected the Account object which has 100s of fields (we've maxed out the allowed number of fields). This errors out with the error below (Requested URI Too Long).

This works fine on smaller tables.

Is there a way to create a custom query that selects only the fields (columns) I want? Either by modifying the automatically-generated query:

```
let
    Source = Salesforce.Data("[salesforce URL]", [CreateNavigationProperties = true]),
    Account1 = Source{[Name="Account"]}[Data]
in
    Account1
```

OR by modifying the actual SOQL request that is sent to Salesforce?

Here's the error

```
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from '[salesforce URL]/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2CIsDeleted%2C<MANY ADDITIONAL FIELDS DELETED>(414): Request-URI Too Long
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Salesforce
    DataSourcePath=[Salesforce URL]
    Url=[Salesforce URL]/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2CIsDeleted%2C<MANY ADDITIONAL FIELDS DELETED>Product_Interest__c%2CFea...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table.SelectColumns` should fold for Salesforce, so see if this works:

```
let
    Source = Salesforce.Data("[salesforce URL]", [CreateNavigationProperties = true]),
    Account1 = Source{[Name="Account"]}[Data],
    Account2 = Table.SelectColumns(Account1, { "First Column", "Second Column" })
in
    Account2
```

Comment: Related question: is there a way to hijack the http request to salesforce and insert my own custom SOQL query?